# python print command output is held back when taking a break from ncurses

Tags: python, ncurses

I have the following simple script which demonstrates my problem:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import curses
import time
import os

screen = curses.initscr()                                       
screen.clear()
screen.addstr(0, 0, "Hello World !!!\n", curses.A_REVERSE)      
screen.refresh()                                                
time.sleep(5)
curses.def_prog_mode()                                          #/* Save the tty modes            */
curses.endwin()                                                 #/* End curses mode temporarily   */

os.system("clear")
ans = raw_input("is the sky blue? (y/n):  ")

if ans == 'y':
        print "yes"

time.sleep(5)

curses.reset_prog_mode()                                #/* Return to the previous tty mode stored by def_prog_mode()     */
screen.refresh()                                        #/* Do refresh() to restore the Screen contents           */
screen.addstr(1, 0, "back in ncurses\n", curses.A_REVERSE)              #/* Back to curses use the full    */
screen.refresh()                                                        #/* capabilities of curses        */
time.sleep(5)
curses.endwin()                                                         #/* End curses mode               */
```

The script leaves curses mode ok, executes clear command ok, waits for an answer from the user ok, but if the answer is y the output yes is not printed to stdout until after ncurses mode is started again.  You can see the yes output in stdout after the script completes, but not before then, even with the time.sleep(5) command.  Is there a way to force the print output to show in stdout before ncurses mode starts again?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest checking out urwid - http://excess.org/urwid/. It's a very well done MVC interface to designing ncurses content and has widgets for all sorts of standard operations.

Comment: Thanks.  I was looking for something like this the other day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flush the standard output.

Try:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```

This should write the output buffer to the terminal and you should see your answer.